# Can I create n rows from one row in google sheets?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, repeat

Here is my data:

```
date            value     repeat    offset
10 September    6         3         1
5 September     5         0         0
11 September    7         0         0
```

I would like the repeats to create new entries, with the offset of offset, in months, so this should output, I have been looking at query and arrayformula, but have no idea how this is best achieved:

```
date            value
10 September    6    
10 October      6    
10 November     6    
5 September     5    
11 September    7
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- add a column with ids for each row (column A in my sample)

**F2**
`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",1,TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&MAX(D2:D4)))*(TRANSPOSE(D2:D4)>=ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&MAX(D2:D4)))),"0"","";;")))),","))`

**G2**
`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("", filter(REPT(A2:A&",",D2:D),A2:A<>"")) , ","))`

**H2**
`=FILTER(VLOOKUP(G2:G,{A:A,B:B},2,),G2:G<>"")`

**I2**
`=FILTER( DATE(YEAR(EOMONTH(H2:H,F2:F-1)), MONTH(EOMONTH(H2:H,F2:F-1)), day(H2:H))  ,G2:G<>"")`

**J2**
`=FILTER(VLOOKUP(G2:G,{A:A,C:C},2,),G2:G<>"")`

More samples of counters [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MgqPVZm5Khackfa1UE9s3aaYskqH8yREdIgVojLhHf4/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Belated congratulations on achieving 10K !

Answer (score 0):

Date is a reserved word so I renamed it.. And the SQL is taken from Oracle.

```
WITH DATA (ADATE,VALUE,REPEAT,OFFSET) AS(
SELECT DATE '2018-09-10',    6,         3,         1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-09-05',     5,         2,         1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-09-11',    7,         2,         1 FROM DUAL 
),
REPEATING AS (
SELECT LEVEL LVL, D.* 
FROM DATA D
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= D.REPEAT
AND PRIOR ADATE = ADATE
and prior sys_guid() is not null
)

SELECT add_months(ADATE,OFFSET*(lvl-1)) "date", value "value"
from repeating;
```

gives the following result:

[image]